# Combining two worksheet change events excel vba

Tags: excel, worksheet, vba

I have tried to figure out how to combine the `Worksheet_Change` events below to run in the same worksheet. They work flawless in different sheets, but not together.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    Range("D4").Interior.Color = RGB(Range("D6"), Range("E6"), Range("F6"))
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("B4")) Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Macro4
    End If
End Sub
```

Any help our guidance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What's the expected and the current outcome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do much...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    Range("D4").Interior.Color = RGB(Range("D6"), Range("E6"), Range("F6"))
    If Intersect(Target, Range("B4")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Macro4
End Sub
```

Comment: LOL - could have made even less changes and simply removed the `End Sub` and `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` lines from the middle.

Comment: Yeah I just automatically get rid of the If Else End If when it's not needed. Can't help it!